# Algebraic Geometry references for shifted structures

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I come from symplectic/poisson geometry and I am curious about shifted symplectic/poisson structure on stacks. From what I've saw, the general context there is derived schemes/stacks, so, Algebraic Geometry.

What would be the shortest (and most useful) reference for learning AG for that? Hartshorne?

Answer (score 1):

Going from Hartshorne to stacks and higher algebra to DAG to derived symplectic geometry would take several years at least. This area arguably began with the paper *Shifted symplectic structures* by T. Pantev, B. Toën, M. Vaquié & G. Vezzosi, so I'd start with the references there and try to backfill any knowledge gaps. Some helpful surveys:

1. [*Derived Algebraic Geometry*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1044) by Bertrand Toën
2. Homotopical algebraic geometry II: geometric stacks and applications by  B. Toën & G. Vezzosi
3. [Derived stacks in symplectic geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.09643) by Damien Calaque. In fact almost everything by Calaque and his students will be useful.

You may also want to take a look at the Stacks project.

Comment: By the way of your **would take several years at least** I recommend the second edition  of I. R. Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry, Volumes 1 (Varieties in Projective Spaces) and 2 (Schemes and Complex Manifolds). Springer- Verlag.